# Modules not loading in platform

Tags: virtocommerce

Despite a successful build, no modules will load. The Browse menu is empty (except for Assets) and custom modules in the Configuration menu are missing.

After downloading the most recent build from our repository, I followed all steps in the "Source Code Getting Started" page. It has been a few months since looking at the VC documentation, and it looks like it has been updated. I recall an extra step after creating the Assets virtual folder in IIS that isn't there now. Is there perhaps a step here that is missing since the docs update?

Fwiw, the build deployed in our QA environment is fine. This is the same code, but I am trying to run locally and am having no luck with modules.

Comment: Open Configuration->Modules->Available check flag  'Show Module bundles' then check 'commerce' modules bundle and click install. After installation restart platform.

Comment: This is what is displayed under Configuration -> Modules: "No Modules found. Check if virtual directory with alias Modules is configured as described in the documentation". There is no step in the Getting Started page involving Modules in IIS, aside from creating an empty folder in ~/vc/platform

Answer (score 0):

Virtual folder for Modules is optional in IIS and this step was skipped in the [updated docs](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/deployment/platform-deployment/source-code-getting-started). But adjusting permissions in needed: "Open properties for **vc-platform\VirtoCommerce.Platform.Web\Modules** (create this folder if not exsist) folder and give permission Modify to IIS_IUSRS user group as shown above."